# Texmaker won't compile unless opened through terminal

Tags: latex

I am running Linux mint 16. I have installed Texmaker on my machine and everything works fine when I open it through the terminal, i.e. `$ texmaker foo.tex`; however, when I open the file by double-clicking on the `foo.tex` file in Nemo and picking `display` (which opens it in Texmaker), I cannot typeset the file. When I try to do a quick build, pdflatex, etc. it IMMEDIATELY displays the log messages from my last build, sits looking like it's doing something for a few seconds (quick build is greyed out) and then does nothing; it doesn't open the pdf as usual, and if I check it separately, it hasn't written anything. I realise this may be a question more suited to tex stack exchange but to me it seems like it's more of a fundamental linux problem (a problem with my knowledge of it that is) because it just depends on how I open Texmaker.

EDIT

I checked the differences in processes when opened both ways;
when opened through the terminal, I get:

```
me 6092 16.6 0.9 497100 55952 pts/3 Sl+ 17:05 0:00 texmaker foo.tex
```

When opened through Nemo, I get:

```
me 6099 13.2 0.9 644560 55972 ? Sl 17:05 0:00 texmaker /home/me/dir/foo.tex
```

Comment: Under the hood, nemo (some file manager, apparently) is calling texmaker in some fashion and mode. I would start by investigating how it is doing so. You could first try doing `ps aux | grep texmaker`, after you have started up texmaker via nemo. Then look at how the process looks when you start up texmaker via the terminal. Compare and contrast, and post in your question if you want. More low-level analysis is obviously possible using trace and such, but that is how I would start.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, thank you for the advice. When opened through the terminal, I get: `me     6092 16.6  0.9 497100 55952 pts/3    Sl+  17:05   0:00 texmaker foo.tex`. When opened through Nemo, I get: `me     6099 13.2  0.9 644560 55972 ?        Sl   17:05   0:00 texmaker /home/me/dir/foo.tex`. The state changes from Sl+ to Sl, along with some other stuff, though I'm not sure what to do with this information. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, paste that in the question, not in a comment, please. It will be easier to read if you format it properly.